# MFC - Is it possible to show a Balloon Tip for any other control then a CEdit?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, mfc

`CEdit` has the member function `ShowBalloonTip`, do you know if there is a chance to show the Balloon Tip for e.g. a `CComboBox`?

[image: balloon tip for CEdit control]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll just need to implement your own balloon tool-tip, or you can just use the 
`CBalloonHelp` class implemented in this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24155/CBalloonMsg-An-Easy-to-use-Non-modal-Balloon-Alter).

The function you need to use is:

```
void CBalloonMsg::ShowForCtrl( LPCTSTR lpszHdr, LPCTSTR lpszBody, HWND hCtrl, HICON hIcon /*= NULL*/ );
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems easy to use, have you self tried it? ... I hope you don't mind that I changed the link to the article describing `CBallonMsg` (the original link refered to an article from 2002).

Comment: No problem. Yes, I've used it, and it works quite well. Just use this function - `ShowForCtrl`.